# InstaPy failing on MacOs 11 with Python3

Tags: python, macos, instapy

I try to setup an instaPy bot, using Python3, and get error
I run the quickstart example only

```
InstaPy Version: 0.6.13
 ._.  ._.  ._.  ._.  ._.  ._.  ._.  ._.  ._. 
Workspace in use: "/Users/*****/InstaPy"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/*****/Perso/botinsta/instapy-quickstart-master/run/../quickstart.py", line 15, in <module>
    session = InstaPy(username=insta_username,
  File "/Users/*****/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/instapy/instapy.py", line 325, in __init__
    self.browser, err_msg = set_selenium_local_session(
  File "/Users/*****/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/instapy/browser.py", line 123, in set_selenium_local_session
    browser = webdriver.Firefox(
  File "/Users/*****n/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/firefox/webdriver.py", line 164, in __init__
    self.service.start()
  File "/Users/*****/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/service.py", line 104, in start
    raise WebDriverException("Can not connect to the Service %s" % self.path)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: Can not connect to the Service /usr/local/bin/geckodriver

[Opération terminée]
```